# Declaration of variables with unknown names

Tags: air, actionscript-3, dynamic-variables

I'm current working on a game engine in which players have an option to create their own world to play and share with others. The engine itself is driven by text files. It is also getting developed in adobe AIR.

I'm wanting players to have the ability to create their own variables to use for the world's they make. The only types they would are int and string variables.

Since I cannot find any resource that will let me dynamically name variables, I was wondering if there is any clever way I could make it act like they are dynamically named. The players will need to be able to give it a name to refer to it and of course contents that they want it to hold.

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Maybe store key-value sets (of variables' names and values) in a dictionary or map of some kind? (I have no experience with AIR...)

Comment: You need to store these variables in the device? (Use PersistenceManager) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are using text files, I assume you are parsing and processing these text files. If that's the case, store the variables in a map as the user defines them. You could use two maps, one for ints, one for Strings, or a single map that has both. The key would be the variable name, which maps to its current value.